Alternative for 'coffee' as a social catch up?
Since there are coffee drinkers, and there are non-coffee drinkers, I am wondering if there is a common alternative for catching up for a coffee that indicates a social catchup but without any particular connotations (i.e. that seems to apply more when you say catch up for a drink). Often the alternative to coffee is tea, but I don't think anyone says 'catch up for tea' to mean anything in particular.
Maybe there are some references or translations from other languages as well that is accepted, but I am curious whether anyone has heard of anything that is used commonly in English (US, UK, etc.).

If you get together with somebody "for coffee", you are under no obllgation to drink coffee. Nearly places that serve coffee also serve tea, herbal tea, hot chocolate, and other non-alcoholic drinks.

Let's meet for a cofftea.

UK English "Let's meet for a cuppa".  Cuppa is common pronunciation of "cup of" and can be used to cover any hot drink, such as tea, coffee, chocolate....

@RuthMcT I'd accept that as an answer, although I suspect that in UK English that might imply tea by default?

Is this question asking about or from the perspective of a specific English-speaking culture? I’m puzzled by the question.  In the coastal US, at least, there are very many ways to invite someone to socialize and most do not involve coffee, or any beverage (let’s get together, let’s meet up, let’s do something, let’s plan something, let’s find a time, etc.)

The neutral word for a non-alcoholic drink would be 'beverage', defined in the Cambridge English dictionary as "a drink of any type" but which is widely understood to refer to warm drinks including coffee, tea, cholcoate etc..

In the corporate world, "catching up for a coffee" is a set phrase for casual 1:1 meeting without a set agenda.  It does not necessarily imply consumption of any beverages, much less coffee.
When meeting someone for a "coffee", I often ask if they want an "actual coffee", and if no, we just talk.  If they say yes, we head to the nearest barista, but they still can and often do opt for a non-coffee beverage.
All that said, if you want an alternative, you can simply drop the coffee and suggest a catch-up.  You can also suggest a sync, but this tends to suggest there's a more serious purpose to the meeting (if you need to sync, the implication is that you're currently out of sync!) and is eg. the preferred term for HR to schedule meetings about unpleasant subjects.

If you drop the beverage in the phrase, it doesn't necessarily mean meeting to sit down and have a chat. Not to mention that walking meetings used to be very popular so a 'catch-up' might not involve sitting down at all :D

Although some people may get coffee in a takeaway cup or insulated cup and walk while drinking it. (Another expression would be "we should get together sometime".)

@StuartF, get together sometime does not accomplish the same purpose, as it leaves entirely open the length and the character of the meeting. An important function of for a coffee is that it indicates how long (approximately) the meeting is expected to last, and that it won't involve a full meal.

@jsw29 that's a really good point you are making in terms of the time. I also think "we should get together sometime" is also something people say without necessarily making any commitment because of its vagueness.

One alternative to 'catch up for a coffee' is to say 'catch up for a chat'. This phrase doesn't specify a drink, making it a neutral option for social catch-ups. You can find numerous examples of 'catch up for a chat' in both Google and Google Books, though the web results mainly appear on Australian and New Zealand websites, suggesting it's more commonly used in these regions.
In the US and UK, 'catch up for a chat' may not be as widespread as 'catch up for a coffee,' but it’s still understood, particularly in more casual or informal settings. For example, people might say 'catch up for a chat over a coffee' or 'catch up for a quick chat'.
Here is the Google Ngram chart with the wild card search "catch up for a *":


Well, I want to see if there is an alternative that doesn't specify a particular drink (e.g. coffee) or imply the generic beverage in a particular context (e.g. catch up for a drink in the US almost certainly means alcohol in my experience). The N-gram analysis is interesting, although I typically hear people say in Australia 'catch up for a coffee' more than anything else (because a lot of people do drink coffee). Once you say 'catch up for a beer' it immediately means something outside of work. Somehow I don't think 'catch up for a beverage' will ever catch on :D
